# Struggling with nested Numpy array when implementing Numba

Tags: arrays, numpy, numba

I've got a Numpy array containing information from 56 x-rays (arr1, Array of float32) with one column containing 56 arrays [95200,2] (arr2, Array of object) related to arr1. My goal is to iterate over both arrays and create a new array containing information from **arr1** for each row in **arr2** (arr_out).

As a way of practise I would like to implement Numba in order to speed things up, this does however throw Numba errors which I have trouble solving.

If I am to understand correctly this is mostly caused by arr2 as it is an array of objects, however I can't get my head working towards a solution.

Could someone give me a push?

My current code;

```
@numba.jit
def fill():
    arr_out = np.empty((0,6))
    row, column = arr1.shape
    for row in range(0,row):
        print('Row number: {}'.format(row))
        matrix = arr2[row]
        matrix_rows = len(matrix)-1

        for m_row in range(0, matrix_rows):
            inp_arr = [np.hstack((arr1[row, 0:4],matrix[matrix_row]))]
            arr_out = np.vstack((arr_out, inp_arr))

    return arr_out
```

**Edit**: I forgot to show the warnings;

```
Compilation is falling back to object mode WITH looplifting enabled because Function "fillspec" failed type inference due to: Untyped global name 'arr2': Unsupported array dtype: object

File "<ipython-input-44-7e98fec24979>", line 7:
def fillspec():
    <source elided>
        print('Row number: {}'.format(row))
        matrix = arr2[row]
```

There are others but if I am to understand correctly they are related to this initial warning. (I don't feel a warning dump will add to my question:))

(The term nested array is correct in this case right?)

**Edit 2**: As pointed out, the defining of arr2 is most likely important;
In order to define arr1 as float I took out arr2 as such;

```
arr2 = arr_orig[:,8]
arr1 = np.delete(arr_orig,8, axis=1)
arr1  = arr1.astype(np.float32)
```

This leaves arr2 as a array of object, however the nested arrays inside arr2 *are* defined as float.

Comment: You *do* define `arr2` somewhere right?  If so, you might want to show that.

Comment: arr2 is defined outside of the function as it is build up from of the initial dataset.

Comment: Yes, but - `arr2` appears from the error message to be `dtype = object`, which usually means there's some error in creation.  If you meant for `arr2` to be of objects, you're kind of out of luck with `numba`

Comment: Ah, my apologies (edit underway)

Comment: @DanielF; Rereading your comment gets me to question my approach. Would there be a more elegant way to approach this?

Comment: Probably, but I have no idea what since can't replicate the problem.  Please try to provide a [mcve] of what you want to do.

Comment: Any objects you pass to a numba function must also be Numba compiled objects.  So you either need to make all the objects in your array numba compiled objects, or you can extract the simple information from those objects that you want to work on (e.g. integer types) and just pass that data to your numba function.

Comment: In regular `numpy` doing `vstack` in a loop is inefficient.  Better to collect items in a list and do one concatenate at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @hpaulj for the awnser, I was struggling my way through a simple problem.

My solution is to put every loop result list into a list, after closing the loops the list is then transformed to an array. Where it first took way to long it now takes up less then 2 min (which does make me somewhat suspicious;)).

Thanks for the help all!

Sidenote; I put a timer on the loops and noticed the time increasing for each loop. This combined with @hpaulj's awnser triggered me to rebuild.